# How creating a multi-dimension array using std::array work?

Tags: c++, arrays

Alright I've already watch Basic CPP online

On Multi dimension array

```
std::array<std::array<int,3>,3>arrayMD = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

This is CPP reference Documentation

the first parameter is a datatype
and the second param is size of the data

```
template<
    class T,
    std::size_t N
> struct array;
```

Why can I pass an array as a data type?

The tutorial doesn't explain this and said it just works.

I have found some article said, "In CS array is a datatype".

Comment: The first template parameter `T` is the type of each element in the array. You can have *any* type for the elements, like other arrays.

Comment: `std::array<int,3>` is itself a type, so why shouldn't you be able to pass that as `T`? In other words `arrayMD` is an array of size `3` with `std::array<int,3>` as each element.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you this clear up a lot, If it was used to set data type inside of array for example `std::array<int,3>arrayMD`  so array would be `arrayMD{ int, int, int}` since value inside of array is `int`  the variable would be `int arrayMD{ int, int , int }`.   In Multi Dimension Data type of arrayMD is another array with int inside how arrayMD set itself to int? does it go through the deepest array to find the data type?

Comment: is your question actually about the `= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` part rather than `std::array<std::array<int,3>,3>arrayMD` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's  the `std::array<std::array<int,3>,3>arrayMD` one. im just confused how arrayMD data type set to int the top reply said The first template parameter T is the type of each element **in the array** so it was to set array inside arrayMD to int not arrayMD itself. So it is by default int? since when I cout arrayMD it output the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have an array like

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> arr;
```

That would be an array of two elements. Each element would be an array of three `int` elements.

It would look something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | arr[0][2] | arr[1][0] | arr[1][1] | arr[1][2] |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```